# Visual Studio looking for a file in the Desktop directory instead of the Project Directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, file-io

I am trying to run the following code in "Start Without Debugging" and "Release" modes.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string word;
freopen("test.txt","r",stdin);
if(cin>>word)
    cout<<word;
else
    cout<<"unable to read"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine in Debug mode but when i run the code in Start without Debugging mode or release mode the output is always "unable to read" unless even if the file is in the Project folder.

What's bizzare is if the file is placed in the desktop directory the code works fine. 
Can anyone explain why visual studio is looking for the file in Desktop instead of the Project Folder when not in Debug Mode ?

Comment: Because that's the directory set as the working directory for the program in release mode? You can change it in the project settings.

Comment: The duplicate question has the opposite problem, but the cause and solution are the same - specify where the program should look.

Comment: The only reason I asked this question is I can't find settings to change the working directory for Release mode. In Debug Mode I would go to ProjectProperties->Configuration properties->Debugging->Working Directory. But I can't find any option of changing the Working Directory in Release Mode.

Comment: @Bo Persson : you should mark this question as not duplicate since the answer for the question you think it is duplicate of does not solve the problem.

Comment: @jumper0x08 - The thing is that there *is* a setting for the VS debugger, but *not* for release mode executables. "Current working directory" is a property of the system, not the executable. So, if you do `open("test.txt")` the file is opened wherever someone else has set the working directory previously. Using a full path name is one way to avoid this.

Comment: Could you clarify what you meant by "wherever someone has set the working directory previously". That someone has to be me but the setting of the working directory should not be irreversible right?